# What are x1_step1_xoffset, x1_step1_gain and x1_step1_ymin in a neural network generated by genFunction in Matlab?

Tags: networking, neural-network, matlab

I'm working with Matlab's Neural Network toolbox and I have generated a neural network function with genFunction.

I would like to know what **mapminmax_apply function** does, **what are these variables used for** and their meaning in the neural network:

```
% Input 1
x1_step1_xoffset = [0.151979470539401;-89.4008362047824;0.387909026651698;0.201508462422352];
x1_step1_gain = [2.67439342164766;0.0112020512930696;3.56055585104964;4.09080417195814];
x1_step1_ymin = -1;
```

Here it's the mapminmax_apply function:

```
% Map Minimum and Maximum Input Processing Function
function y = mapminmax_apply(x,settings_gain,settings_xoffset,settings_ymin)
    y = bsxfun(@minus,x,settings_xoffset);
    y = bsxfun(@times,y,settings_gain);
    y = bsxfun(@plus,y,settings_ymin);
end
```

And here it's the call to the function with the above variables:

```
% Input 1
Xp1 = mapminmax_apply(X{1,ts},x1_step1_gain,x1_step1_xoffset,x1_step1_ymin);
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the documentation of the `mapminmax_apply` function? I was only able to find [`mapminmax`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mapminmax.html) which has an option `'apply'`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I can't provide a link to the documentation because this function has been generated by genFunction so I only have the function itself. However, seeing the documentation you provide about mapminmax I think it does the same, thank you very much. Now my question is what the 3 input variables mean and how they're calculated.

Comment: I'm not sure I can provide an answer here. What is the reason for using a home-brew function instead of Matlab's function? Where does it come from? Maybe you are better of asking those that implemented the version of `mapminmax` you are using. Without seeing that function it is difficult to help you.

Comment: I want to have a neural network that depends only on weights and biases, how to get rid of these extra parameters?

Answer (score 1):

I think:

the mapminmax function can also return the settings it uses (amongst others, offset, gain and ymin). For some reason in the code spat out by the NN function, these settings are given at the begining of the file, under Input1, in the form of x1_step1_xoffset, etc.

mapminmax('apply',X,PS) will apply the settings in PS to the mapminmax algorithm.

So, I think the code generated here has more steps than you necessarily need. You could get rid of the Input1 steps and just use a simple xp1 = mapminmax(x1'), instead of the mapminmax_apply

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Matlab NN toolbox automatically normalizes the features of the dataset.

The functions **mapminmax_apply** and **mapminmax_reverse** are related to normalizing the features.

The function **mapminmax_apply** exactly converts/normalizes input range to -1 to 1.

Since the output will also come out as a normalized vector/value(between -1 to 1) it needs to be reversed normalized using the function **mapminmax_reverse** .

Cheers